# Unable to assign response.data into a variable in nodejs but is coming in console.log()

Tags: node.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
let api = []
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/make_json/', {
  api:"{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/1190896199.pdf', 'Title': 'Corrigendum'},{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/3916152215.pdf', 'Title': 'Notification '},{'Link': 'http://www.nia.nic.in/', 'Title': ' Official Website'}"
})
.then(response => {
  api = response.data
})

console.log(api)
```

here i am assigning response to a variable api which is defined on the top. but when i am trying to console.log() it is coming blank arrray..

please have a look into my code..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I am not able to figureout same. could you please write it ??

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log()` statement returns a blank array because it is being executed before the response from your POST request is returned. This is due to the fact that `axios` executes requests [asynchronously](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/how-node-and-javascript-handle-asynchronous-functions-7feb9fc8a610).

To access the data returned from the network request without writing other functions, you need to have your code in the `then` block like so:

```
const axios = require('axios');  
let api = []  
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/make_json/', {
  api:"{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/1190896199.pdf', 'Title': 'Corrigendum'},{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/3916152215.pdf', 'Title': 'Notification '},{'Link': 'http://www.nia.nic.in/', 'Title': ' Official Website'}"
})  
.then(response => {  
  api = response.data  
  console.log(api)
  // other code using `api`...
})
```

Another option, if you're using at least version 7.6 of Node, is to wrap your code in an `async` function and `await` the result:

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function myCode() {
  const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/make_json/', {
    api:"{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/1190896199.pdf', 'Title': 'Corrigendum'},{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/3916152215.pdf', 'Title': 'Notification '},{'Link': 'http://www.nia.nic.in/', 'Title': ' Official Website'}"
  })

  let api = response.data
  console.log(api)
  // other code using `api`...
}

myCode() // note that `myCode` will run asynchronously
```

Comment: I don't think that it's possible without somehow forcing `axios` to run synchronously. In my second example, you would be able to put all of your code into the `myCode` function and write your program in a synchronous style - it just requires calling that function. What is your specific use case that you need the console statement outside of the function?